# Python3.6 function not called

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm developing a `REST` API in Python 3.6 using `Flask-Rebar` and `PostgreSQL` and am having trouble trying to execute some queries simultaneously using `psycopg2`.

More specifically, I execute a query and require the `id` value from this query for use in the next query. The first query successfully returns the expected value, however the function that calls the subsequent query doesn't even execute.

Here is the function responsible for calling the query function:

```
psql = PostgresHandler()

user_ids = [1, 5, 9]
horse = {"name": "Adam", "age": 400}

def createHorseQuery(user_ids, horse):
    time_created = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

    fields, values = list(), list()

    for key, val in horse.items():
        fields.append(key)
        values.append(val)

    fields.append('time_created')
    values.append(time_created)

    fields = str(fields).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')').replace("'", "")
    values = str(values).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')

    create_horse_query = f"INSERT INTO horse {fields} VALUES {values} RETURNING horse_id;"

    horse_id = None
    for h_id in psql.queryDatabase(create_horse_query, returnInsert=True):
        horse_id = h_id

    link_user_query = ''

    for u_id in user_ids:
        link_user_query += f"INSERT INTO user_to_horse (user_id, horse_id) VALUES ({u_id}, {horse_id['horse_id']});"

    psql.queryDatabase(link_user_query)

    return horse_id, 201
```

Here is the `PostgresHandler()` class that contains the function `queryDatabase`:

```
class PostgresHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connectToDatabase()

    def connectToDatabase(self):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
            host        = '...',
            user        = '...',
            password    = '...',
            database    = '...'
        )

    def queryDatabase(self, query, returnInsert=False):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)

        cursor.execute(query)

        if "SELECT" in query.upper():
            for result in cursor.fetchall():
                yield result
        elif "INSERT" in query.upper():
            if returnInsert:
                for result in cursor.fetchall():
                    yield result

            self.connection.commit()

        cursor.close()
```

I can verify that the `psql.queryDatabase(create_horse_query, returnInsert=True)` operation is successful by querying the database manually and comparing against the return value, `h_id`.

I can verify that `link_user_query` is created and contains the `user_ids` and `horse_id` as expected by printing. I know the query that's generated is okay as I have tested this manually in the database.

It appears that the function called on the line `psql.queryDatabase(link_user_query)` is never actually called as a print statement at the *very top* of the `queryDatabase` function does not get executed.

I've tried with delays between the two query function calls, initialising a new connection with each function call and many other things to no avail and I am absolutely stumped. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: FYI, The `createHorseQuery` function returns successfully and displays the two returned values as expected.

Comment: Just a sidenote, I see way too much string manipulation. Your current approach is just an SQL-inject attack waiting to happen. I would suggestion looking into `flask-sqlalchemy` or some other higher level library.

Comment: Thanks @Joost, there is *other* validation going on, but I definitely see where you're coming from. I'll look into `flask-sqlalchemy`; anything to not have this horrible string manipulation!

Comment: What if the user posts a horse named 'SELECT123'? This line: `if "SELECT" in query.upper():` would be triggered. Then you have to do all kinds of magic to see if a horse contains any SQL terms or punctuation etc. SQLalchemy takes a bit of time to learn, but it saves you much time, bugs, and security problems in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryDatabase` in your code is a generator because it contains a [yield](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/#specification-yield) statement. The generator only actually does things when you iterate over it (i.e. cause `__next__()` to be called). Consider the following:

```
def gen():
    print("Gen is running!")
    yield "Gen yielded: hello"
    print("Gen did: commit")

print("***Doing stuff with b***")
b = gen()
for a in b:
    print(a)

print("***Doing stuff with c***")
c = gen()

print("***Done***")
```

Output is:

```
***Doing stuff with b***
Gen is running!
Gen yielded: hello
Gen did: commit
***Doing stuff with c***
***Done***
```

When we called `gen()` to create `c` we didn't actually run it, we just instantiated it as a generator.

We could force it to run by calling `__next__()` on it a bunch of times:

```
c.__next__()
try:
    c.__next__()
except StopIteration:
    print("Iteration is over!")
```

outputs:

```
Gen is running!
Gen did: commit
Iteration is over!
```

But really, you should probably not use a generator like this where you are never intending to `yield` from it. You could consider adding a new function which is not a generator called `insertSilently` (or similar).

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly my mistake. I assumed that the function wouldn't be treated as a generator if I had the conditional to never make it to the yield, obviously I was wrong. Much appreciated.